# Making an NSImage from an 2d array of ints

Tags: c#, cocoa, nsimage

Hi im working on a program to load DICOM-files (medical fileformat for images) and display them in a mac os cocoa app. Im coding in C# using visual studio.

Ive gotten to the point where i can make a 2d array of ints representing the intensity, there is no color.

I do not know how to make this into a NSImage so that i can use it as an image in cocoa.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish this, depending on your needs, but the "modern" method is to use the `NSImage` class factory method:

`+ (instancetype)imageWithSize:(NSSize)size flipped:(BOOL)drawingHandlerShouldBeCalledWithFlippedContext drawingHandler:(BOOL (^)(NSRect dstRect))drawingHandler;`

This method takes a block parameter with the code that turns your data into an image, just as if you were drawing it onto the screen for a custom `NSView` implementation. (If you've never done this before, start with [Cocoa Drawing Guide: "Views and Drawing"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/DrawingEnviron/DrawingEnviron.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH202-SW19) as well as ["Graphics Contexts"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/GraphicsContexts/GraphicsContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH203-BCIJFBJJ).

The factory method is smart and (unless the resolution of your screen changes), it will only be called once and the resulting image cached in the `NSImage`'s representation.

The next alternative (which might actually be easier for you) is to translate your `int` array into an RGBA (or whatever) buffer representing the pixel values in the image. This process begins by creating a specific `NSBitmapImageRep` (this is a "representation" object—each `NSImage` is a collection of one or more representations).

This will require some research into the various pixel buffer formats, but it's also pretty easy to do. Once you've built your 2D pixel buffer representation, you can turn that directly into an `NSImage`.

These, and other techniques, are explained in the [Cocoa Drawing Guide: "Creating NSImage Objects"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-SW20).